# Efficient storage of overlapping sets

Tags: database-theory

I have a bag of sets which overlap, and I am looking for an efficient (if possible, optimal) way to leverage that overlap to store those sets with minimal space requirements. For example, consider these two sets:

```
S = {1,2,3,4}
T = {2,3,4,5}
```

An efficient storage solution would somehow make use of the overlap, e.g.

```
X = {2,3,4}
S = {1} + X
T = {5} + X
```

The query pattern I'd need to support is retrieving all the sets that contain a given member (sets would be labelled, so retrieving all the labels). Ideally I'd also like to be able to retrieve the members of any given set (by label) efficiently, but that is not as important.

Is this an instance of a well-known problem? Any pointers towards literature, or a solution, would be much appreciate.

Comment: Are you going to start with the set $X$ followed by several union of $X$ with other sets before you perform the query? Or you are going to start with $S$ and $T$  such that the elements are stored while taking advantage of the overlap?

Comment: I think this equivalent to minimising a circuit for a bundle of boolean functions. Tools include [Espresso](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer#ESPRESSO_algorithm).

Comment: How many distinct elements ? How many sets ? Distribution of the set sizes ? Distribution of the number of sets for a given element ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any one-size-fits-all answer to this problem.  In the worst case, no compression is possible.  Which compression algorithm is best is going to depend on the distribution of problem instances that you see in real life.  That information is not provided, so the question is not answerable.